# Transfer data on a 3.3V high speed UART (> 20 MBaud) to a PC terminal application?

Tags: usb

On my PCB I have a ball grid array microcontroller with a 3.3V GPIO pin that I'm generating a UART Tx-only waveform on using bit-banging, as an alternative to trace. The particular pin is not hooked up to any hardware peripheral (UART, USART, SPI, timer, etc). My SystemCoreClock is 216 MHz and the faster I can make the UART run (20 MBaud or faster), the less it will interfere  with the rest of my code.

Can anybody please suggest a way to transfer the data on the UART-pin to a PC terminal application?

Comment: I would be quite hesitant to use an UART at such speeds. I’m actually surprised it goes that high, and I’m not sure there are any devices that support it. There are probably better options for such speeds,if you let us know more about the scenario. Ethernet would probably be the first alternative to explore, though there are probably many others.

Comment: Hi arnold_w, we don't do product recommendations as per our rules. You could, however, describe your situation, say what you need that extremely-high-speed UART for, and describe that you haven't been able to find an IC that translates UART to USB at that speed. As jcaron hints at, at such high speeds, UART usually ceases to make any sense, so before I recommend any workaround for your problem, I'd actually would want to know what problem you're **actually** trying to solve.

Comment: It has a 1 kilobyte buffer, so depending on driver, it is possible that you can not get sustained 12Mbps transmissions, but bursts of transmissions at 12Mbps. But before you try, are you sure you even want an UART? Many MCUs have built-in USB these days.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways, first you need to find out the logic levels of the output of the micro controller. Most microcontollers use 3.3V logic levels (TTL or CMOS, and this determines how a 1 or 0 is transmitted)

I think the easiest way to get data out of a microcontroller is to use a USB to UART converter like the FT232RQ (or equivalent), which can be purchased at many hobbyist electronic distributors like adafruit or sparkfun.

These convert logic level serial to USB (it shows up as a serial port, you can then read the data with any program that can talk to serial like realterm, c , python, matlab ect)

[image]
Source: http://www.datasheetdir.com/Usb-To-Rs232-Uart-Serial-Converter-Pcb%2BApplication-Notes

You don't need the RTS and CTS lines (but they are better for flow control if you need more accurate data), you'd only need the RX line connected to the tx line on your microprocessor.

Another thing that I've done is a virtual com port with usb to the processor, but most micros only support 'regular' USB speed which is 12Mbps.

Comment: My microcontroller has 3.3V GPIO:s. Unfortunately, it seems FT232RQ only goes up to 3 MBaud: https://ftdichip.com/products/ft232rq/

Comment: If you want to go faster, it get's much harder, becasue after 20MHz you have to start impedance matching to get rise times. You can have easy and you can have fast, but you can't have both. You  could go with a FTDI quad spi with parallel channels or something like that, but that makes things harder not easier.

Comment: I don't mind giving impedance matching a try.

Comment: Other thing, I doubt you can get a bit banged UART to 20MHz on an micro. I tried toggling a pin an I had a hard time getting it to 40MHz on an STM32F4, and you can't use the HAL either. The periphrials won't go past 50MHz on most micros, if you want to go faster you need transceivers.